Call Recording Issue on Android OS
`
Desc
When attempting to record calls using the VOICE_COMMUNICATION audio source on Oppo phones, the recording functionality is disrupted once a call is initiated. The microphone stops recording at the start of the call and resumes only after the call ends. This issue specifically impacts Oppo devices.
note
when using VOICE_CALL or VOICE_DOWNLINK the app crashes but with VOICE_COMMUNICATION recording well but mic muted in call
Expected Result:
The microphone should continuously record audio during the entire call without interruption.
Actual Result:
The microphone stops recording at the start of the call and resumes only after the call ends, causing a loss of audio data during the call.
`

package com.ertaqy.recorder.base.audiorecord

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import javax.inject.Inject

class AndroidAudioRecorder @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context ,
): AudioRecorder {

    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null

    private fun createRecorder(): MediaRecorder {
        return if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            MediaRecorder(context)
        } else MediaRecorder()
    }

    override fun start(file: File?) {
        if (file == null) {
            Log.e("Recorder", "Invalid file path")
            return
        }

        // Check permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e("Recorder", "Required permissions not granted")
            return
        }

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            try {
                val mediaRecorder = createRecorder()
                val audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION
              //  if (isAudioSourceSupported(audioSource)) {
                    mediaRecorder.apply {
                        setAudioSource(audioSource)
                        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
                        setOutputFile(FileOutputStream(file).fd)
                        prepare()
                        start()
                        recorder = this
                   // }
                    Log.d("Recorder", "Recording started with VOICE_DOWNLINK: ${file.absolutePath}")
                } /*else {
                    Log.e("Recorder", "Audio source VOICE_DOWNLINK not supported on this device")
                }*/
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Recorder", "Failed to start recording", e)
                recorder?.release()
                recorder = null
            }
        }
    }
    // Check if the audio source is supported
    private fun isAudioSourceSupported(audioSource: Int): Boolean {
        return try {
            val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
            val devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS)
            devices.any { it.type == audioSource }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Recorder", "Error checking audio source support", e)
            false
        }
    }
    override fun stop() {
        recorder?.stop()
        recorder?.reset()
        recorder = null
    }
}

